# ¿Código ASCII en C++?

Tags: c++, ascii

sabemos que en código **ASCII**:
*á = 160    é = 130 í = 161 ó = 162 ú = 163*

Intento probar el código **ASCII en C++** y he notado esto.

Mi código en C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    printf("%c\n",160); // Imprime á
    getchar();
}
```

Ahí funciona perfectamente. Ahora pruebo con este:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    int s = 162; // La ó en código ASCII
    char car = char(s);
    printf("%c",car);
    getchar();
}
```

Funciona perfectamente el **código ASCII**. Pero si hago esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    char car;
    scanf("%c", &car);
    if(car=='á'){ // Valido que sea á de una forma muy directa
        printf("YES");
    }
    else{
        printf("NO");
    }
    getchar();
}
```

**Introduzo á.
Me dice NO.** A lo mejor sea porque no lo reconoce el programa, lo cambio por este:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    char car;
    scanf("%c", &car);
    if(car==160){ // á en ASCII
        printf("YES");
    }
    else{
        printf("NO");
    }
    getchar();
}
```

**Introduzco á.
Me dice NO de nuevo.** Ahora convierto el carácter en número y lo comparo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    char car; int numcar;
    scanf("%c", &car);
    numcar = int(car); // Convierto el carácter a el número que lo representa
    if(numcar==160){
        printf("YES");
    }
    else{
        printf("NO");
    }
    getchar();
}
```

**Introduzo á.
Me dice NO otra vez**, entonces el **ASCII no está funcionando**. Ahora imprimo el 
número del carácter introducido:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    char car; int numcar;
    scanf("%c", &car);
    numcar = int(car);
    printf("%i", numcar); // Imprimo el número del carácter
    getchar();
}
```

**Introduzco á, se supone que debe imprimir 160, pero imprime -61.**
Ahora modifico la condición:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    char car;
    scanf("%c", &car);
    if(car==-61){ // El valor dado anteriormente
        printf("YES");
    }
    else{
        printf("NO");
    }
    getchar();
}
```

**Introduzco á.
Me imprime ahora YES**, ahora lo intento con é:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    char car;
    scanf("%c", &car);
    if(car==130){ // é en ASCII
        printf("YES");
    }
    else{
        printf("NO");
    }
    getchar();
}
```

**Introduzco é. Me dice NO**, hago de nuevo el proceso de mostrar el número y me sale **de nuevo -61**. Intento convertir el -61 a carácter y me sale uno que es diferente a *(á,é,í,ó,ú)*.

**¿Por qué sucede esto? ¿Es otro código diferente a ASCII? ¿Me falta una librería?**

**Mi proposito es validar las vocales con acento, ¿Por qué no funciona el código ASCII?**

Todo los códigos han sido mostrados tal y como estaban en el IDE sin editar nada. IDE: CodeBlocks con estandarización de c++14.

Comment: El estándar de C no especifica si `char` es `signed`o `unsigned`por default. Te recomiendo en la siguiente instrucción `char car = char(s);`definir a `car` como `unsigned char`

Comment: Quisiera ahondar en mi respuesta porque es un tema confuso de C++ pero necesito de tu retroalimentación para saber si lo sucede lo que te comento..

Comment: Necesitas usar la libreria de string.h para imprimir un texto
Lee un poco sobre esta libreria!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es debido a estándares de codificación. El error es que se asume que es está usando **ASCII extendido** cuando en realidad se está usando **UTF-8**.

El código correspondiente en **UTF-8** para el caracter **á** es **0xc3a1**.
Puedes comprobar el valor [aquí](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e1/index.htm)

Esto lo podrás comprobar con el siguiente código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    printf("%x\n",'á');
}
```

Ahora, cuando ejecutas lo siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    char car; int numcar;
    scanf("%c", &car);
    numcar = int(car);
    printf("%i", numcar); // Imprimo el número del carácter
    getchar();
}
```

Al ejecutar la siguiente instrucción:

```
    scanf("%c", &car);
```

Al limitar la variable `car` al tipo `char` y analizando el comportamiento que obtienes, podemos decir que siendo que el caracter necesita **2** bytes para ser almacenado **(0xc3a1)**, estás truncando uno de los bytes y el programa termina almacenando solo la porción mas significativa **(0xc3)**.

Ahora, si pasamos el valor a decimal (signado), nos dá como resultado **-61**

Qué es lo que puedes hacer?

Desconozco si `scanf` puede obtener caracteres de **UTF-8**. Tendrás que recurrir a un truco como [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113270/how-to-read-unicode-utf-8-binary-file-line-by-line), en donde los caracteres extendidos no se tratan como caracter sino como cadena.

Comment: He probado el código que me dijiste, efectivamente el rango de bits interfería en el valor del carácter, pero ahora el valor de "á" cuando lo introduzco

Comment: He probado el código que me dijiste, efectivamente el **número de bits** interfería en el valor del carácter, pero ahora el valor de "á" cuando lo introduzco, **no es 160**, es **195**, además lo intente con (é, í, ó, ú) y me da exactamente **195** como su valor en número en todas las vocales.

Comment: Tienes la alternativa mostrada arriba. Guardar la entrada como entero, no como char, y hacer la comparación con su valor en UTF-8

Comment: si tienes razon ya lo probe con UTF-8 y ya valida las volcales, gracias.